# Cannot connect to MSSQL server using FreeTDS on Raspberry Pi (Rasbian)

Tags: sql-server, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, freetds

I am trying to connect to an MSSQL Server database, which is a named instance, from my Raspberry Pi running Rasbian, using FreeTDS.  My server\instance name is DISRUPT-L02\SQLEXPRESS2014 so my freetds.conf file looks like this:

```
[SQL] 
host = DISRUPT-L02
instance = SQLEXPRESS2014
tds version = 7.0
dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
```

Then I run `tsql -S SQL -U {username} -P {password}` I get an error `There was a problem connecting to the server` and the log file reports the following lines:

```
net.c:936:tds7_get_instance_port({ip address}, SQLEXPRESS2014)
net.c.987:tds7_get_instance_port: timed out on try 0 of 16
net.c.987:tds7_get_instance_port: timed out on try 1 of 16
...
net.c.1059:instance port is 0
login.c.436:invalid port number
```

I have checked that UDP port 1434 is open on the server and the SQL server allows remote connections.

I have tried all sorts of combinations from suggestions on other sites but I cannot get this to connect.

I'm sure it's something simple I have missed but I can't for the life of me work this out.

Comment: What happens if you `telnet DISRUPT-L02 1434`? Is the SQL Server browser service running on the server?

Comment: The instance discovery logic is extremely simple: it will send a one-byte UDP packet (specifically, byte `3`) to port 1434 and wait one second for a reply on the same port. The error message you're reporting is when there is no reply. Either the incoming or outgoing packet is blocked by a firewall on either device, or the SQL Server Browser service is not running. There really aren't many more options. I can confirm that sending such a packet will cause the SQL Server Browser to respond with a list of all instances on the machine.

Comment: Well now my stupidity is obvious; the SQL Browser service was disabled.  Thanks @JeroenMostert for the tip

Comment: Not sure how to nominate a comment as the solution so that points are awarded though

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Jeroen Mostert, the SQL Browser service was not started.  Started this server, restarted everything and it worked perfectly.